# react router error with a switch no idea what did wrong here

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

i need your help so goes like this
i got this error
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use  outside a 
invariant
D:/laragon/www/Projects/trello-clone/node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.esm.js:10
(anonymous function)
D:/laragon/www/Projects/modules/Switch.js:17

the code https://gist.github.com/Sivanwol/e16cd1aad2ee63a596afad9715bb2e33

so  what i did wrong

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're importing Router from 'react-router' and importing Switch from 'react-router-dom'?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the sintax:

The sintax that React Router 5 uses for creating Routes is:

```
<Route path="/about">
    <About />
</Route>
```

But the sintax for creating Routes in React Router 4 (which is the one you say are currently using), is:

```
<Route 
    path={"/about"} 
    component={About}
/>
```

or in case you want to pass some props:

```
<Route 
    path={path} 
    component={
        (props) => <About someProp={props.someProp}/>
    }
/>
```

Hope this helps